# Is there a way to know whether a method is an operator?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have a list of method names :

```py
['__add__', 'upper', '__mul__']
```

**Is there a way to know whether they are operator methods ?** (*Note that detecting dunders is not enough, as not all dunder methods are operators*)

---

My class is monkey-patched with those operators, and I'd like a way for the monkey-patcher to know whether the method is an operator instead of having to tell it so.

This would make using the 'reverse operator' (ex : `other.__radd__(self)`) when the normal one is `NotImplemented` easier.

```py
def make_wrappers(cls, operators =[], methods=[]):
    """Make wrapper methods for the given class

    This rewires self.method to self.value.method
    
    operators will also try the reverse operator
    ex : __add__ will try __radd__ if __add__ returns NotImplemented
    """

    for method in operators:
        def wrapper(self, other, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
            """Tries operator on self.value, then reverse operator if NotImplemented"""
            result = getattr(self.value, _method)(other, *args, **kwargs)

            if result is NotImplemented:
                _method = f'__r{_method.strip("_")}__'
                result = getattr(other, _method)(self.value, *args, **kwargs)

            return type(self)(result)

        setattr(cls, method, wrapper)
    
    for method in coercedMethods:
        def wrapper(self, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
            return type(self)( getattr(self.value, _method)(*args, **kwargs) )
        setattr(cls, method, wrapper)
    
    # This makes sure ABC doesn't refuse instanciation
    cls.__abstractmethods__ = cls.__abstractmethods__.difference(operators, methods)
```

Comment: I don't think so. The relationship between operators and dunder methods is arbitrary.

Comment: @barmar I found the solution myself ! I'm writing it right now, check in in like two minutes if it interests you

Comment: You must [wait 48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to accept your own answer.

Comment: *I found the solution but I can't accept my own answer on my own question for some reason ?* - You can, you just need to wait 48 hours... [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). This is to allow for other users to show-up with maybe other solutions that you like more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I found how to do it ! Just `import operator` and check `if method in dir(operator)`

```py
import operator

def make_wrappers(cls, methods=[]):
    """Make wrapper methods for the given class

    This rewires self.method to self.value.method
    
    operators will also try the reverse operator
    ex : __add__ will try __radd__ if __add__ returns NotImplemented
    """
    for method in methods:
        if method in dir(operator):
            def wrapper(self, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
                return getattr(operator, _method)(self.value, *args, **kwargs)
            setattr(cls, method, wrapper)
        else:
            def wrapper(self, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
                return getattr(self.value, _method)(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(cls, method, wrapper)
    
    # This makes sure ABC doesn't refuse instanciation
    cls.__abstractmethods__ = cls.__abstractmethods__.difference(coercedMethods, nonCoercedMethods)
```